# scrollbar overflow when a dialog popup happens

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, angular-material

I am building a Twitter clone with angular, I want the scrollbar of the dialog which appears when I click a tweet to be far right of the browser like Twitter what happened instead of that a scrollbar overflow

I tried not to set the width of the dialog but it didn't solve the scrollbar overflow problem

```
openDialog(kweek: Kweek): void {
    this.roots.push(kweek);
    this.popUpMode = true;
    const dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();
    dialogConfig.width = '640px';
    dialogConfig.data = { roots: this.roots };
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ReplyComponent, dialogConfig);
    dialogRef.componentInstance.roots = this.roots;
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      this.roots = [];
    });
```

Comment: the scrollbar overflow problem is solved by using div instead of mat-dialog-content but now there is no scrollbar at all, I still want to scroll the dialog using the far right scroll bar (main scroll bar)

Comment: can you share a stackblitz ?

Comment: Could you add html and css code? i think you should have alook on inspect element and add `overflow`

Comment: html/css: https://codepen.io/abdulrahman-khalid/pen/rbwqWw

Comment: I solve it using this line befor opening the dialog:

   dialogConfig.scrollStrategy = this.overlay.scrollStrategies.reposition();

Comment: also added this to css code:
.cdk-global-overlay-wrapper {
  pointer-events: auto;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.cdk-global-overlay-wrapper::before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.cdk-overlay-pane {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  text-align: left;
  white-space: normal;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: -50px;
}